# Why is it not possible to PXE boot Ubuntu Desktop editions?

Tags: 18.04, pxe

I am using [Cobbler](http://cobbler.github.io/) to PXE boot Ubuntu 18.04 Server edition. However, it seems impossible to PXE boot Ubuntu Desktop image. What does make this difference? Is it possible to make Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop edition work over PXE boot?

Comment: I have successfully made Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop PXE-boot (I use it regularly to recover people's laptops here, and the same mechanism does my workstation deployment). I'm having problems with 18.04 recognising a USB adapter, but I imagine it will work once I've solved that. Have you tried PXE-booting the desktop edition? If so, what errors do you get?

Comment: How did you PXE boot the desktop edition?

Comment: You might want to visit this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029017/pxe-boot-of-18-04-iso

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that it is possible to PXE-boot 18.04 Desktop using the following setup:

- `tftpd-hpa`
- `nfs-kernel-server`
- `lighttpd`
- `ipxe`

Below are the iPXE instructions I used to PXE-boot:

```
#!ipxe

set server_ip <PXE server IP>

:start
menu Please choose an operating system to install
item --gap Ubuntu Live
item 16.04 Ubuntu 16.04LTS Live Boot
item 18.04 Ubuntu 18.04LTS Live Boot
...
:18.04
kernel installroot/Ubuntu/18.04/amd64/vmlinuz boot=casper netboot=nfs nfsroot=${server_ip}:/srv/pxe/installroot/Ubuntu/18.04/amd64 initrd=initrd.gz toram
initrd installroot/Ubuntu/18.04/amd64/initrd.gz
boot || goto failed
```

The problem you are having may be more specific to Cobbler. Please either clarify your question or post the error you are experiencing.